# Homebrew: installation of ruby-build fails with "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I'm trying to install Ruby on my Macbook Air. So I put like this:

```
brew install ruby-build
```

But, the answer I got is Error and warnings like this:

```
==> Pouring openssl-1.0.2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz  
Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass  
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.  
Error: /usr/local/opt/makedepend not present or broken  
Please reinstall makedepend. Sorry :(
```

What is wrong and what do I do?

Comment: If you haven't already, try running `brew upgrade`, then attempt `brew install ruby-build` again.

Comment: Thank you! That helped! Finally ruby installation is done.